# Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 Software Updater often failed

Tags: update-manager

Just want to ask, why my software updater always says failed to download repository, the dialog box like this

[image]

My internet is working fine i already checked, i am on Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 using Dell Vostro Laptop

Comment: Tha error message is often misleading. Any unaccessible software source, typically third party PPAs, can trigger the error. Do it in Terminal so you can check the error messages which should be self-explanatory but in any case you may want to [edit] and post those error messages.

Comment: @MichaelBay thanks for the information, i finally understand why this problem keep bugging me and i already solved it by removing unaccessible ppa.. and yeah the error message is really misleading.. Thanks